# abntcite: use Author (Date) instead (Author, Date)

Tags: citing

I'm using `abntcite.sty` and I'm a noob.
I like to know how to change my `\cite{}` look like "Author (Date)" instead "(Author, Date)", but I dont know how. I've tried so many ways, but I could not.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/abntex2/doc/abntex2cite-alf.pdf) you should use `\citeonline` for Author (year) citations and `\cite` for (Author, Year) citations.  If this doesn't solve your problem, then post a minimal working document that shows exactly what you are doing.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX! it might be helpful to take a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  It's usually very important to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) with a question like this.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn, but it didn't work. It shows "Author, Date" instead "Author (Date)". I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @SamuelJr, did you read the section 4.2 from the documentation cited above by @Alan?

Comment: Yes @Sigur. When I said that "It didn't work" it meant that I had read the section 4.2 and I used \citeonline{}. According the documentation, it should have worked for me, but it didn't. I think that there is another configuration in my project which is causing this problem. Thanks everyone for helping me

Comment: @SamuelJr, do you have an updated version of the package? Try to make a minimal file reproducing the problem and then we can try to compile it.

Comment: I received the template from a colleague of university. I'm using ShareLatex. I'll looking for a way to share the code.

Comment: @SamuelJr Sharing your entire code is not the way to solve this.  You need create a small document that shows the problem.  The process of doing so may help you figure out the problem  yourself (it often does), but if it doesn't edit your question and add the minimal document that creates the problem.

Comment: I'm very busy and I was working in another things, but I finally find out where is the function what make the string. It's on file "abnt-alf.bst":
<code>
FUNCTION {calc.simple.label}
{ author empty$ not
    {author format.names.for.label1}
    {editor empty$ not
     {editor format.names.for.label1}
     {organization empty$ not
      {organization}
      {title empty$ not
       {title}
       {""}
      if$}
     if$}
    if$}
   if$
 year empty$ 'skip$ {", " * year *} if$ 
}
</code>
The only thing that I have to know is: How can I put "(" and ")" around year?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example (of the sort you could have constructed). I'm using the latest version of the `abntex` class, from TeXLive 2014:

```
% !BIB TS-program = bibtex

\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside,a4paper,brazil]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

@book{Chomsky1957,
    Address = {The Hague},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {Mouton},
    Title = {Syntactic Structures},
    Year = {1957}}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Um}
Um exemplo de referências explícitas: \citeonline{Chomsky1957} e \citeonline{Labov1972}  têm idéias diferentes sobre a linguística.

Um exemplo de referências implícitas: Têm idéias diferentes sobre a linguística, por exemplo \cite{Chomsky1957, Labov1972}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the output is as expected (apart from the awful use of upper case, which you are apparently stuck with.)

[image: citations]
[image: references]